# Numeric Text box accepts "E" character

Tags: html, angularjs, regex

I have a text box with the following regex pattern

`ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,6}$/"`

It restricts all characters but not E

Is there a solution for this using regex?! I wonder.

Comment: `10e+1` is numeric.

Comment: Change `type="number"` to `type="text"`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential

Comment: because 1.23e4 is valid number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Changing number to text works. But it allows keying in characters in to the text box. Initially it didnt allow keying in of characters except 'E'

Comment: If you only allow typing digits, add `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-pattern` validation does not work for input of `"number"` type, you need to change it to `type="text"`.

To only allow numeric input, add

```
onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
```

to the `input`.